# How to see what caused "A task was cancelled" error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that is running on Azure and over the past few months on a couple of occasions the site has frozen and I can't see any services that are down and the only thing I can see error log wise is the following which doesn't really help.  I have been able to restart the site and it has worked just fine but I need to see what is going wrong.  When I do get the error below I get hundreds of them at the same time.

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Well it does help in that it tells you that a task was cancelled.... typically due to a timeout or something of that nature. So next get the timestamp of this error message and compare with IIS logs / diagnostics and see what request made the application hang. That should give you a fairly good starting point to debug the error. 1/ you know what request is causing it /2 you know it's task/async related /3 look for anything connection related - i.e. a db call.